# Find the equations of all planes that pass through the points (1,1,1) and (2,0,1) and also are tangent to the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves

Find the equations of all planes that pass through the points (1,1,1) and
(2,0,1) and also are tangent to the surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$

Comment: OK, what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Misread the question.

<s>For our purposes it is useful to view this sphere as the level surface (three-dimensional analogue of the contour lines for functions of two variables) of the function $f:x,y,z\mapsto x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$. This is because the gradient $\nabla f(a,b,c)$ of $f$ at a point $(a,b,c)$ is normal to the level surface $\{ (x,y,z) \in\mathbf{R}^{3} : f(x,y,z) = f(a,b,c) \}$ at the point $(a,b,c)$, a fact we can use to build our tangent plane: for example, since</s>

$$ \nabla f (1,1,1) = \begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix} $$

we have that

$$ 2(x-1) + 2(y-1) + 2(z-1) = 0 $$

is the equation of the plane tangent to the to the sphere at one of your points $(1,1,1)$.

[This may help as well](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html)

Comment: The problem is over conditioned and can be misleading by "all planes" or "pass through the points (1,1,1) and (2,0,1)"!

Comment: Oh! Had not noticed! Thanks for pointing it out. Agh, I didn't even bother to check that the points were not even in the surface (my answer doesn't even make sense, given that they aren't), and just assumed it was that stereotypical multivariable calc problem.